# Multiple fade animations using keyframes causing transparency after end

Tags: html, css, css-animations, fade, keyframe

I have a fade keyframe animation on the body of a page. I also want to add an additional keyframe animation on an element so it comes in just after.
This element overlaps another and even after completion of the animation, it has ever so slight transparency causing the element below to show through. You can see this better on high gamut displays.

Chrome only.
Tested OK in Firefox and Edge

[Edit}
Running the snippet below doesn't recreate the issue but in CodePen you can see it

https://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/LYEOQPz

```css
div {width: 300px; height: 300px;}
.one {
  background-color: black;
}
.two {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: -100px 0 0 100px
}

body {
    animation: fade 1s ease forwards;
}
.two {
    animation: delayed-fade 1s ease forwards;
}

// animation: fade 2s ease forwards;
@keyframes fade {
    0%   {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 100%;}
  }

// animation: delayed-fade 4s ease forwards;
@keyframes delayed-fade {
    0%   {opacity: 0;}
    20%  {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 100%;}
  }
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

[image: Overlapping boxes]

Comment: unable to replicate this issue in Chrome - displays with no signs of residual opacity

Comment: It is very hard to see but definately there. I can supply a screenshot to that effect if it helps. I also have a codepen of it here https://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/LYEOQPz.

Comment: It displays fine for me - even setting `.two` as white with a border to see it there is no trace of the black square visible at all when the animation finishes

Comment: I've just looked and while I can see the problem both on my original code and in Codepen, in the snipped above I can't see the effect.

Comment: Id be intrigued to see the screenshot showing this effect

Comment: @RamRaider, the screenshot is in the original post.
Color overlapping the black #fefe01
Color over the white#ffff02